# receive Stream with gst-rtsp-server

Tags: c++, gstreamer, ogg

I have a question about gstreamer.
i made a streaming server using gst-rtsp-server. I'm trying to send camera capture to another machine (on the local network) and to parse it into an .ogv file.

The transmission of the streaming works fine, and i'm able to parse the informations into the file; but i can't read it or use it with any application after this parsing. It seems that there are some information missing (probably in relation with the encoding technique, i don't really know much about it)

Server side command (inside c++ code):

```
....
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory, "( v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videorate !         
video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240,framerate=30/1 ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace !
theoraenc ! rtptheorapay name=pay0 pt=96 )");

gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared (factory, TRUE);

/* attach the test factory to the /test url */
gst_rtsp_media_mapping_add_factory (mapping, "/stream", factory);
....
```

Client side command (terminal command) :

```
gst-launch -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.0.115:8554/stream ! 
rtptheoradepay name=pay0 ! oggmux ! filesink location=/home/jean/Desktop/stream.ogv
```

Any help any kind of help is well appreciated !

Jean

Comment: does anyone has an idea?

Comment: If this is still up-to date, you might want to add information regarding what error is the RTSP client application showing.

Answer (score 0):

I could decode the pipeline as follows to view it `gst-launch -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://localhost:8554/test" name=demux demux. ! queue ! rtptheoradepay ! theoradec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink`

To decode it

`gst-launch -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://localhost:8554/test" !  application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtptheoradepay ! theoradec ! videorate ! ffmpegcolorspace ! theoraenc ! oggmux ! filesink location=GIBBERISH.ogg`

I decode it and encode it back with the videorate before writing to the file. There may be a more optimal way to perform the same but it is just a work around.